# How to feed a different Dropout p value after training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In Tensorflow I would have a `placeholder` such that I can feed it to the network as required:

```py
self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

# ...

# Add dropout
with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
    self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, self.dropout_keep_prob)
```

However, I am not sure how to do this in Keras:

```py
# in_dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")
in_dropout = Input(shape=(1,), name='dropout')

# ..

# Add droppout
droput = Dropout(in_dropout)(max_pool) # This does not work of course
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keras `Dropout` layers behave differently in training and test phase, that is its only enabled in training phase.

To use dropout in through training/test phase you have to replace the Dropout layers with `Lambda` layers using `dropout` function from keras backend.

```
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras import backend as K

model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.dropout(x, level=0.5)))
```

For more reference check: [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1606).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Even though it's in the docs somehow I didn't get it that it's actually not being used while testing.